# Text files embedded into a DLL: how to dynamically create a dictionary from them

Tags: c#

I have a library with several text files as embedded resources like the following photo:

[image]

by running following line we have a string with the content of text file

```
Properties.Resources.CanadianCities
```

we need to know the name of the embedded resource ( `CanadianCities` ).
so, in future, I added a new text file to embedded resource and I update my packages (UKCitites.txt). I want a dictionary in my DLL to cache the value of all text files (the text files are embedded resources). So, I **do need** the dictionary dynamically fetch the new embedded file.

- `Key`: embedded file name
- `Value`: the content of file

Comment: Can you clarify your question? It's a little ambiguous whether you need to know how to create a dictionary or find embedded files. A very specific question stands far less chance of getting closed for being too broad".

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to read embedded resource text file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3314140/how-to-read-embedded-resource-text-file)

Comment: See the comment at the end of the accepted answer, that's what you are looking for

Comment: @RufusL Updated

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto Updated

Comment: It's still a duplicate of the question I linked. Just read each resource name and then their contents

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto I do not see that. can you provide a clue for me please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are getting your resources from member properties of the  `Properties.Resources` class, and all the resources that you need are exposed, then you can create a dictionary of them with this LINQ:

```
using System;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Linq;
using System.Collections.Generic;

Dictionary<string, object> resourceDictionary = typeof(Properties.Resources)
        .GetProperties
            (
                BindingFlags.Static
              | BindingFlags.Public
            )
        .ToDictionary
            (
                p => p.Name, 
                p => p.GetValue(null) 
            );
```

Comment: smart trick. ResourceManger does not provide any solution for this problem?